# Azure Blob Storage - Static Site analytics

Tags: azure-web-app-service, cloudflare, azure-blob-storage

I've got a static web site hosted in Azure Blob Storage with Cloudflare as my CDN.  It's such a small site (not even 1Mb and only 1 blog post), but I'm getting 1.1-1.2Gb of requests each month for the past 6 months or so with no explanation.  Is there a way to find out what is being requested?  In Azure, I can only find information about the performance, up-time, etc, but nothing about url's and I need to pay to get this info from Cloudflare (I believe).  Has anyone else experience such strange requests?

Comment: I wonder if your problem is solved? Does my answer help you? If there is a better way to solve this problem, you can also send your own answers, which can better help others in the forum.

Comment: @Jason, I had some things blow up at work and have been working huge hours on that. Finally got to have a look at your answer this morning and it works a treat, thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you open `Diagnostic settings` and download `Azure Storage Explorer` to view the logs.

[image]

When you finished settings, u can check logs by tools. You can see request urls and http status info.

[image]

The previous data should not be visible, but you can monitor and analyze future requests.

Comment: It actually appears to be Cloudflare smashing me... I'll leave this run for a day and see what results I get

Answer (score 0):

[image]
When I did a lookup on those two IP's, they were both registered to Cloudflare, one makes sense given I'm using their service, but to have what appears to be their bot hit my site with this frequency doesn't... Wonder if there's a setting